# LUIS API - Is there an endpoint to test utterances?

Tags: javascript, api, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

I'm creating an application that interfaces with the LUIS API. The api seems to provides most everything I need except for a way to test utterances against the app's intents.

This guide from Microsoft details what I'm talking about specifically
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/train-test

Is anyone familiar with a way to test a batch of sample utterances programmatically using the API? I checked every endpoint and it seems to be missing. Either that or I'm the one missing something.

LUIS API Docs
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/58aeface39e2bb03dcd5909e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently don't have that feature of batch testing using Programmatic API. It might be considered in future. The only way for batch testing currently is through [UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/train-test) as you have mentioned earlier. And you can submit a [feature request](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis) here.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I'll submit a feature request :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. The updated API list is given here in [link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78).Here there are two methods  (Get)Get predictions from endpoint and (Post) Get predictions from endpoint.

Comment: This API call only supports single utterances, not batch testing as requested by the OP